# Distributional equations: reference request

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, textbook-recommendation, books, schwartz-distributions

I'm really having a hard time finding a book that covers distributional equations such as $xT = \delta(x)$ or distributional differential equations. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem of division of distributions. The general existence theorem is the Malgrange-Ehrenpreis Theorem. The first two volumes of Hörmander's "The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators" is a canonical reference. See also [this book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-20140-5) by Ortner and Wagner.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @AbdelmalekAbdesselam's mention of the canonical Hormander, there are some "lighter" physical-book sources that also illustrate operational use of the ideas. The best conventional book I know is G. Grubb's "Distributions and operators". (She is in Hormander's "school"...)

Comment: May I draw your attention to this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/259834/nice-apps-for-schwartz-distributions I am sure you might have some nice suggestions.