# The "Spaces of Schwartz distributions are finite dimensional" challenge

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, big-list, schwartz-distributions

The more I study Schwartz distributions and the corresponding spaces, the more the latter look "finite dimensional" to me. Of course they are not finite dimensional in the *technical sense* but they are **essentially finite dimensional** in the sense that "theorems which are true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ should be true for them too".

I would like to get a better hold on what "essentially finite dimensional" should mean. So I propose this question/challenge (maybe this should be made community wiki?).

> **Question:** Can you find examples of theorems which only use the topological vector space structure of $V$ and are true when $V$ is finite dimensional, typically false when $V$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space, but true again when $V$ is $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (with the strong topology).

Here are some example to get started.

1. A subset $A$ of $V$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded.
2. $V$ is reflexive.
3. A sequence of Borel probability measures on $V$ converges weakly iff the characteristic functions $V'\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ converge pointwise to a function that is continuous at the origin.

*I would prefer examples of properties/theorems which are not entirely a consequence of being nuclear.*

---

Motivation:
I don't yet have a definition of "essentially finite dimensional" (EFD) which is a fluctuating concept to me. 
Of course EFD should be of the form "nuclear+some mystery ingredients". I am hoping the answers to the question as I asked it would tell me more about the optimal mix of mystery ingredients rather than the nuclear part. One might think that what I am after is a phrase-definition like "nuclear, barrelled and quasi-complete" but it is not quite that as I try to explain in what follows.

The definition of finite dimensional vector space is that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. This involves a *concrete model* as a space of functions on a discrete set, here the finite set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. I suppose EFD could be defined similarly, as follows. Let $\Omega$ be a set of "pre-seminorms" on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. By "pre-seminorm" I mean the same definition as seminorm but allowing the value $\infty$.
Then define $V=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} | \forall \omega\in\Omega, \omega(x)<\infty\}$ with the topology defined by the restrictions of the elements of $\Omega$ which then become true seminorms. I suppose one could restrict to $l^1$ pre-seminorms of the form
$$
\omega(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\omega_n\ |x_n|
$$
with weights $\omega_n\ge 0$. What I would ultimately like is an explicit property of $\Omega$ which makes the corresponding space as close as possible to a finite dimensional space. The part of that property concerning nuclearity was worked out at long time ago by Grothendieck for echelon spaces and Pietsch in general. The property should be "The Pietsch criterion+???".

Anyway, all I asked is examples of theorems, the more surprising the better, and the further away from just being nuclear the better too.

---

Motivation for the motivation: I have been thinking about how one could improve existing presentations of the theory of distributions, see e.g.
[Nice applications for Schwartz distributions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259834/nice-applications-for-schwartz-distributions) One approach I am exploring is to use sequence space representations and I would eventually like to narrow down the possibilities to a class of $\Omega$'s which is easy to define and could serve as "optimal" class of concrete models for EFDs.

Comment: [Nuclear space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space)?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: Of course that's a first approximation to the notion of "essentially finite dimensional" (EFD). However, my question is not to find a good definition of EDF (which I think is premature) but to give me a list of examples of the kind of theorems satisfied by EDF spaces. So to reiterate "nuclear space" is completely off the point.

Comment: Surely there is a more polite way to indicate that a reasonable answer is not the sort you want than to say that it "is completely off the point".  (It doesn't seem fair to say that @MateuszKwaśnicki was *re*iterating, since your post doesn't directly mention nuclear spaces ….)

Comment: @LSpice: My comment was not impolite and MK's answer was not reasonable. I admit: what I say is not always clear. What I find annoying is quick judges who read what I say in an absent-minded fashion and when having to choose between multiple interpretations, pick the most silly one. Example 1: I did not say He was reiterating, but I was reiterating. MO comments do not allow corrections like "So, to reiterate:" instead of "So to reiterate". Example 2: I did not ask for a definition like "nuclear space" but for a list of examples. BTW "Nuclear space?" as an answer is sassy if not impolite

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Even if it is not a complete answer, surely the definition of nuclear space, restated as a theorem, is one example of a theorem satisfied by finite-dimensional spaces and Schwartz spaces but not typical infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: By no means I intended to offend you. I just wanted to point out that the properties that you listed (as well as, for example, Schwartz kernel theorem and Bochner's theorem, listed in the linked Wikipedia entry) are specific to nuclear spaces. If you are looking for other properties, you may want to explain in what sense your concept of *essentially finite-dimensional* spaces is supposed to be different from the notion of nuclear spaces.

Comment: @Will: true. The nuclear property is of course part of the EFD but not all of it. It is the most obvious part and therefore of little interest to me. What I didn't like is not the content of MK's comment but its form. I made some effort in writing my question and what I got is a two word answer posted as comment with a poky "?" and a link to wikipedia for my personal edification...

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: The clue was in item 2 in my question. Nuclear is not enough for strong reflexivity. But I guess you did not pay attention to that.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: Honestly, I do not know why you take this personally, I really wanted to help.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: So far I did not see anything resembling an apology, just doubling down, people ganging up and getting upvoted. Go figure. I think I will delete this question altogether because, apart from Peter Michor's answer, I did not get any useful or constructive contributions.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I see no need for an apology. You're seeing a personal affront where none was intended. In fact, Mateusz was moments faster before I would have posted a similar (but longer) comment. Nuclearity is an obvious first thought here and I (who don't know you or the amount of your knowledge) cannot see any reason not to cover the obvious thoughts first, before we move on to different approaches. I agree with Mateusz on the point that it may be helpful to explicate exactly what differences to nuclearity you want to have...

Comment: .. For example nuclear+quasicomplete+barrelled implies strong reflexivity. Does the combination nuclear+quasicomplete+barrelled satisfy your intuition of "essentially finite-dimensional" ? If not, why not? I for one would think that a very reasonable approximation to my intuition of these words.

Comment: @JohannesHahn: I just edited the question while you were typing your comment. "nuclear+quasicomplete+barrelled" is not bad but not what I want as hopefully my update should clarify..or not.

Comment: No, I think it is much clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: I thought for a bit about where I think the misunderstandings lie between you and the commenters and upvoters on your question that lead to disagreement even though no one was trying to be impolite. I have more thoughts, but let me just say that a comment is not always for the benefit of the question asker. I suspect many of the upvoters were people who, like me, were not so familiar with nuclear spaces, and found Mateusz's comment helpful, and thus were surprised by your reaction, but didn't really intend to gang up on you.

Comment: @Will: There are several issues to be disentangled here. The first one is: was MK's comment disrespectful or not? I say it was. As I mentioned above a two word answer with a questionable question mark sounded sassy to me. The second one is was there intent to be disrespectful? MK said not and I believe him. This is a bit like say in the subway person A steps on person B's foot. Normally person A would say something like "Sorry I didn't mean to" to which person B, even with an aching foot, would reply "no worries" and everybody would get on with their lives...

Comment: ...Both "Sorry" and "I didn't mean to" are important. It's not because there was no ill intent that there was no stepping on foot. MK said "I didn't mean to" but did not say "Sorry". This looks like an apology but it is not. This is amplified by comments like JH's. It's like telling person B "you're dreaming and making a fuss about something that did not happen" or "there was no intent and therefore nobody stepped on your foot". In any case, the initial incident is utterly insignificant and I would have been happy to totally forget about it, with or without "sorry"...

Comment: ...then came the much less excusable comment by LSpice which unleashed the mob on me. From that point on it became necessary for me to stand my ground. Returning to JH's comment and continuing my subway scene analogy, only person B has a right to make the determination that an apology is called for or not. Bystanders C,D, E,...who only saw part of the scene and have incomplete information have no right to tell person B "nobody stepped on your foot" because it's not their foot.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I enjoy discussions of this type and I hope you don't find my attempts to provide advice presumptuous. Consider a modification of your analogy - what if they accidentally step on your foot and you respond by intentionally stepping on theirs? If they had intentionally stepped on your foot then this was a reasonable response - I think I did exactly this with my brother in childhood. If they had not intentionally stepped on your foot, then this was an unprovoked attack.

Comment: From the point of view of bystanders, while perhaps they should apologise, your attack is a much more serious matter, and you should apologise first. This goes double if it is not clear to people what about their comment was offensive in the first place. In this kind of situation I do not think it is necessary, or helpful to stand your ground. An alternate approach would be to apologise (maybe an incomplete apology) for your response, explain what you found offensive in the original answer, and request clarification. I don’t see how this would cause a problem in the future.

Comment: What can I say. I am 100% to blame. The mob is (always) right. If that's what you want to hear.

Comment: I found @MateuszKwaśnicki's first response very useful and interesting, not having heard of nuclear spaces. Moreover, I think his intended reading of it was "Nuclear spaces?" --> "What about nuclear spaces? Are those kind of what you are looking for?" not, as I suspect you heard it "Wow can't believe you haven't heard of nuclear spaces." It's a simple misunderstanding, the kind that is common on comment threads the world over. I don't see why anybody should let that get in the way of thinking about and discussing what is in fact a very interesting question.

Comment: I really enjoy analyzing these social situations for the same way I enjoy mathematics. For that reason, I would be happy to hear that you now agree with me, and also happy to hear a full-throated defense of your position. Anyways, thanks for indulging me for a while.

Comment: I found the 'nuclear spaces?' comment a bit irritating as well.  Anyone who knows the definition of the topology on $\mathcal{S}'$ can be presumed to know about nuclear spaces.  Doubly so for someone like Abdelmalek, whose profile and comment history both indicate that this sort of thing is his bread and butter.  It's reasonable to ask if nuclear space is intended to be part of the answer, but it's a bit obnoxious to toss off a two word comment with no further clarification.  The question may not have been perfect, but it deserved a bit more consideration than that.

Comment: Storm in a teacup?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: Yes. That about sums it up.

Comment: @cbartondock: Thank you. Your comment prompted me to try to salvage this question.

Answer (score 14):

Like others have pointed out the key, concept is that of nuclear spaces and a good presentation can be found in  volume 4 of Gelfand's *Generalized Functions*.

Kolmogorov has  introduced a concept  of dimension of a functional space and the nuclear spaces  have   finite Kolmogorov dimension; see Chap I. Sec. 3.8 of the above reference. For example,  in this section it is proved the space of real analytic functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has Kolmogorov dimension $n$.  As an aside,  this concept of dimension   has lead to   proofs of many generalizations of Hilbert 13th problem.

The above reference also contains a beautiful presentation of the Schwartz kernel theorem. I recommend  this source  enthusiastically.

Comment: Thank you Liviu. I looked at bits and pieces of the Generalized Functions series, but that was a while ago. I also share your high esteem for this work, see for example what I said at the end of https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03180 My (perhaps faulty) recollection was that they only considered the countably Hilbert particular case of Grothendieck's nuclear property. In any case your answer prompts me to go have a second look at the books.

Comment: Yes, it is true that they cover only countable Hilbert spaces but this covers  the spaces needed in distribution theory.

Answer (score 13):

Every short exact sequence $$0\to \mathscr S'\to Y\to \mathscr S'\to 0$$ (where $Y$ is any locally convex space) splits, i.e., the quotient map $Y\to \mathscr S'$ has a continuous linear right inverse. The same for $$0\to \mathscr D'\to Y\to \mathscr D'\to 0$$ where $Y$ is any so-called PLS-space. These are very particular cases of the splitting theory for Frechet spaces (plus duality) and PLS-spaces developped by Palamodov and Vogt (and others, in particular, Wagner, Domanski,...). These results use more than the forbidden property.

Comment: Thank you Jochen. This is the kind of answers I was hoping for. There is no forbidden property. It's just that I prefer theorems which do not only rely on the nuclear property.

Answer (score 9):

The Schwartz kernel theorem: For a manifold $M$ we have
\begin{multline*}
\mathcal D'(M\times M)  = 
(\mathcal D(M)\hat{\hat\otimes} \mathcal D(M))'
= (\mathcal D(M)\hat\otimes \mathcal D(M))' = L(\mathcal D(M), \mathcal D'(M))\,.
\end{multline*}
where one needs first the completed inductive or $\epsilon$-tensorproduct, and then the projective one. Fortunately they agree by who shall not be named, just like in finite dimensions.

Comment: The injective tensor product of the space of test functions on the real line with itself isn't the space of test functions on the plane!

Comment: @Peter: Thank you! I suppose the first equality uses more than the TVS structure and so does not fit the format of my question, but the last one does.