# Is the tensor product of distributions a continuous bilinear map with respect to the weak topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth manifolds. The map $\mathcal{D}'(X)\times\mathcal{D}'(Y)\to\mathcal{D}'(X\times Y)$ given by $(S,T)\mapsto S\boxtimes T$ is continuous with respect to the strong topology. Is it continuous with respect to the weak-* topology?

Comment: If one uses the correct topology which is the strong dual topology then the map is continuous. I don't think it is continuous if one equips these spaces with the weak-$\ast$ topology. By continuous I mean continuous, not sequentially continuous.

Comment: If $S_\alpha$ and $T_\beta$ converge weakly to $S$ and $T$ in $\mathcal{D}'(X)$ and $\mathcal{D}'(Y)$, respectively, then $S_\alpha\boxtimes T_\beta$ converges pointwise to $S\boxtimes T$ on the dense subspace of $\mathcal{D}(X\times Y)$ spanned by all functions of the form $f\boxtimes g$. But, if it is true, I do not see how to show that $S_\alpha\boxtimes T_\beta$ converges pointwise to $S\boxtimes T$ on all of $\mathcal{D}(X\times Y)$.

Comment: That's the point, it's not true. Why do you need the weak topology? It's the wrong one to use for this kind of question.

Comment: I agree that the weak topology is the wrong one. The reason I asked the question is because I have a situation where I have sets of distributions $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{D}'(X)$ and $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathcal{D}'(Y)$, and I want to show that the image of $(\mathcal{S}^\perp)^\perp\times (\mathcal{T}^\perp)^\perp$ in $\mathcal{D}'(X\times Y)$ is contained in $((\mathcal{S}\boxtimes\mathcal{T})^\perp)^\perp$.

Comment: Ah, good question. I retagged the post so hopefully experts on topological vector spaces can help. These notes seem to have an interesting discussion of the operation of double orthogonals https://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~enigsch/lehre/lcs.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will use the convention $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and denote by $s(\mathbb{N})$ the space of (real) sequences $(\mu_i)_{i\ge 1}$ of rapid decay, i.e., such that for all integer $k\ge 0$,
$$
\|\mu\|_k:=\sup_{i}i^k|\mu_i|\ <\infty\ .
$$
We give it the locally convex topology defined by the norms $\|\cdot\|_k$, indexed by integers $k\ge 0$.

The dual can be identified with the space $s'(\mathbb{N})$ of sequences $(a_i)_{i\ge 1}$
which grow at most polynomially in $i$.
We will write
$$
\langle \mu,a\rangle:=\sum_i \mu_i a_i 
$$
for the duality pairing.

We can similarly define the two index generalizations $s(\mathbb{N}^2)$ and $s'(\mathbb{N}^2)$.
The analogue of the tensor product of distributions is the map $s'(\mathbb{N})\times s'(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow s'(\mathbb{N}^2)$ given by $(a,b)\mapsto a\otimes b$ where
$$
(a\otimes b)_{i,j}:=a_i b_j\ .
$$
Saying that this bilinear map is continuous, where all spaces carry the weak-$\ast$ topology amounts to saying that $\forall \rho\in s(\mathbb{N}^2)$, $\exists p, q$, $\exists \mu^{(1)},\ldots,\mu^{(p)},\nu^{(1)},\ldots,\nu^{(q)}\in s(\mathbb{N})$, such that $\forall a,b\in s'(\mathbb{N})$,
$$
\left|\sum_{i,j}\rho_{i,j}a_i b_j\right|\le\left(\sum_{m=1}^{p}|\langle\mu^{(m)},a\rangle|\right)
\times
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{q}|\langle\nu^{(n)},b\rangle|\right)\ .
$$
**Lemma:** Let $\mu^{(1)},\ldots,\mu^{(p)}$ and $\mu$ be elements of $s(\mathbb{N})$.
Suppose that for all $a\in s'(\mathbb{N})$, if $\langle\mu^{(1)},a\rangle=\cdots=\langle\mu^{(p)},a\rangle=0$ then $\langle\mu,a\rangle=0$.
This hypothesis implies that $\mu$ is in the linear span of $\mu^{(1)},\ldots,\mu^{(p)}$.

For the proof, package the $\mu$'s into a $(p+1)\times\infty$ matrix and do row operations to reduce to row echelon form.

The above inequality and the lemma immediately show that the rows of the matrix $\rho_{i,j}$ must span a finite-dimensional space. So, pick say $\rho_{i,j}=e^{-i}\delta_{i,j}$ and this proves that **the tensor product is not continuous for the weak-$\ast$ topology**.

Now, as I said in my comment, **the correct topology to use is the strong topology**. If all spaces carry it then saying that $(a,b)\mapsto a\otimes b$ is continuous amounts to saying

$\forall \rho\in s(\mathbb{N}^2)$, $\exists p, q$, $\exists \mu^{(1)},\ldots,\mu^{(p)},\nu^{(1)},\ldots,\nu^{(q)}\in s(\mathbb{N})$, such that $\forall a,b\in s'(\mathbb{N})$,
$$
\sum_{i,j}\left|\rho_{i,j}a_i b_j\right|\le\left(\sum_{m=1}^{p}\sum_i|\mu^{(m)}_i a_i|\right)
\times
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{q}\sum_j|\nu^{(n)}_j b_j|\right)\ .
$$

See the difference? One has traded absolute values of sums for sums of absolute values.

The statement about the strong topology is true, with $p=q=1$, because given $\rho\in s(\mathbb{N}^2)$, $\exists \mu,\nu\in s(\mathbb{N})$,  such that for all $i,j$,
$$
|\rho_{i,j}|\le |\mu_i|\times|\nu_j|\ .
$$

Finally, using isomorphisms with sequence spaces the above proofs also shows continuity of the tensor product operation $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})\times\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$.