# Early successes of Schwartz distribution theory

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, ho.history-overview, schwartz-distributions

What are the *early* successes of Schwartz distributions theory?
What are the hard theorems that became simple and what
open problems were solved with this new tool soon after Laurent
Schwartz released his book in the fifties?

Answer (score 15):

Following the [citation](https://www.mathunion.org/imu-awards/fields-medal/fields-medals-1950) for the 1950 Fields medal I would argue that putting the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) on a firm ground was *the* early success of the theory of distributions.$^\ast$

An extensive list of (later) applications is at [Nice applications for Schwartz distributions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/259834/11260)

---

$^\ast$ Incidentally, this is Dyson's take on applications of the theory of distributions in physics [[source](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.3062600)]

> The theory of generalized functions (alias distributions) is the only
> part of post-war pure mathematics which has turned out to have a
> genuine usefulness in physics. In fashionable field-theoretic circles
> a paper can now hardly be submitted for publication without at least a
> reference to Schwartz's two-volume Théorie des Distributions. In some
> recent papers one can find evidence that Schwartz's work has not only
> been quoted but has even been read. Applications of distribution
> theory are being found all over physics, in nonlinear mechanics and
> fluid dynamics as well as in field theory.

Comment: The firm ground for the Dirac delta function might look like nitpickery by mathematicians but for computations with distributions this is useful for practical applications. If you don't know what distributions are and how to work with them it can easily happen that you accidentily include 1=0 into your assumptions and then go on to prove amazing things. Having a precise definition helps you sort out what you can and cannot do with a Dirac delta and helps sort out which results are actually true.

Comment: @quarague --- it might be of interest to give an example of a case where a naive use of the delta function gives a wrong result (I don't quite have an example ready myself).

Comment: Here is a contrived example. Let $f$ be the function defined by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x \neq 0$. Now integrate $f$ as a test function against the Dirac delta distribution on the interval $[-1,1]$. If you do it naively, that is treat both as regular functions, the result is zero. If you do it properly the result is $1$.

Comment: Here is an example where not using the Dirac function does not give the correct result. Let us try to solve the differential equation $y''+y = 0$ using the Fourier transform. We get $(1-\xi^2) \hat{y}(\xi) = 0$ which has no interesting function as a solution. It has however the two distributional solutions $\delta_{-1}$ and $\delta_1$ that account for the two classical solutions $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$ of the original equation.

Comment: It seems to me that the "Dirac function" was already put on a firm ground with the advent of measure theory and Lebesgue integral, with the concept of Dirac measure. Also, it became pretty standard in probability theory after the work of Kolmogorov to embed positive integrable functions iin the space of measures by seeing them as densities. And this matches pretty closely the use of the "Dirac function" in physics as a distribution of masses.

Comment: @quarague Could you refer to a rigorous formalism having functions like your $f(x)$ among test functions?

Comment: @quarague I don't understand your example. Your $f$ is zero a.e. with respect to the Dirac measure, which is an atomic measure supported at $\{0\}$. What did you mean when you said that the result would be $1$ if it is done properly?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Here's a naïve failure of $\delta$. Let $H$ be the Heaviside step function, with $H' = \delta$, and note that, under pointwise multiplication of functions, $H^n = H$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\delta = H' = (H^2)' = 2HH' = 2H\delta$, but also $\delta = (H^3)' = 3H^2 H' = 3 H \delta$. So $H\delta = 0$ and therefore $\delta = 0$. As a distribution, $H^n$ doesn't exist, and certainly doesn't equal $H$.

Answer (score 10):

This is a very broad topic. If you want a nice little book on the use of distributions in mathematical physics, I suggest [this one](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/ru/library/books/Demidov2001en.pdf) by Demidov. In the Preface and in Chapter 1, Section 1, the author deals a bit with the history of the concept of function and the role there played by generalized functions (a particular case of which, in his terminology, are Schartz distributions).

The book proceeds by showing how some classical PDEs of mathematical physics admit a much more natural and explicative solution if considered in weak form, and how this is further generalized in the theory of distributions. I also quite like the final chapter on the (underestimated, in my opinion) concept of "generalized function according to Egorov".

So all in all I think this may be a useful read for your aim. But please notice that, as usual in the Russian school, quite a bit of work, including some key proofs, is left to the reader in the problems.