# If a function is in a Sobolev space, what can we say about its square?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If I have a function $f \in H^s(\mathbb R^n)$, what can I say about $f^2$? In particular, I'm interested in the case when $s < 0$ and would like to conclude that, for example, $f \in H^{2s}(\mathbb R^n)$. Is something like this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, something like this is not true. In any negative Sobolev space, you can find a function f with a point singularity such that $f^2$ is not integrable. Hence $f^2$ is not even a distribution, and certainly not in $H^{2s}$.

Comment: Thanks! Would the additional hypothesis that $f$ is regular help at all?

Comment: Yes. If $f$ is in $H^s$ with $s>n/2$, then $f^2$ is also in $H^s$. But not in $H^{2s}$.

Comment: To clarify: is there something more we could assume about $f$ such that it would not imply is was in some $H^s$ with $s > 0$, but would let us say that $f^2 \in H^{s'}$ for $s' < 0$? You stated the issue in general with $f \in H^s$, $s < 0$, is that $f$ could have a singularity. But this I assume you mean some akin to a delta function. Is that right? What if we assume $f$ doesn't have any such singularities? E.g. $f$ is a distribution that can be represented by a function. Would some such assumption suffice to ensure $f^2$ is a well-defined distribution and, moreover, in a Sobolev space?

Comment: Well, yes. For instance if f is in $L^2=H^0$, then $f^2$ is in $L^1$, and by Sobolev embedding $f^2$ is in $H^{-r}$ for every $r>n/2$. You can argue along similar lines if $f$ is in $H^s$ for $0<s\le n/2$.

Comment: This also provides a partial answer to my follow-up question: [Is square of Delta function defined somewhere?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48067/is-square-of-delta-function-defined-somewhere)